# Why following trace norm inequality valid?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I was reading article named Determining Conductivity by Boundary Measurements by Robert Kohn and Vogelius. In need that I stuck at following one point.

We denote by $H^{s}(\Omega), s \geqq 0$, the standard Sobolev space of order $s$ based on $L^{2}(\Omega)$, with norm $\|\cdot\|_{s, \Omega}$. Auther writes following.

It is well known that
$$
C^{\prime}\|\phi\|_{W^{\frac{1}{2}, 2}(\partial \Omega)} \leqq \inf _{\substack{\left.v \in H^{1}(\Omega) \\ v\right|_{\partial\Omega}=\phi}}\|v\|_{W^{1, 2}(\Omega)} \leqq C\|\phi\|_{W^{\frac{1}{2}, 2}(\partial \Omega)},
$$
I know that the trace operator is the bounded linear operator between space $W^{1, 2}(\Omega) \rightarrow W^{\frac{1}{2}, 2}(\partial \Omega)$. So we have
$$
C^{\prime}\|\phi\|_{W^{\frac{1}{2}, 2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq \inf _{v \in W^{1, 2}(\Omega),\left.v\right|_{\partial \Omega}=\phi}\|v\|_{W^{1, 2}(\Omega)}
$$

But I do not understand that $$
 \inf _{\substack{\left.v \in H^{1}(\Omega) \\ v\right|_{\partial\Omega}=\phi}}\|v\|_{W^{1, 2}(\Omega)} \leqq C\|\phi\|_{W^{\frac{1}{2}, 2}(\partial \Omega)}
$$

Any help or refernce will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this uses the existence of an (bounded and linear) extension operator $E:W^{1/2,2}(\partial\Omega)\to H^1(\Omega)$ such that $Eu|_{\partial\Omega}= u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace operator is not only linear continuous from $H^1$ to $W^{1/2,2}$ (aka $H^{1/2}$), it is also onto, and there exists a linear continuous lifting from $H^{1/2}$ to $W^{1/2,2}$. The inequality you mention corresponds to this continuity.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me is there any reference for such theorem in case of $W^{s,p}$ space? I have also asked this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407954/reference-request-for-trace-theorem-for-ws-p-omega-space

Comment: I would recommend to check in R. Adams, J. Fournier, "Sobolev Spaces", Academic Press 2003.